# How to unbind events for specific keys

Tags: javascript, jquery-events

I'm suspecting that some jQuery plugins that I'm using are interfering with my keyboard arrow key presses by having specific events bound.

Assuming I don't care about breaking whatever it is they're doing, how can I unbind all events for, say, the left and right arrow key presses?

How would one debug or see a list of events that are fired upon key pressing? (I don't know which lines of code are currently handling the key presses, if any)

Comment: You could write listen key events from body , and when specific keys are pressed , in your callback function , return false.

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind that without affecting other bound keypress events:

```
$(document).unbind("keypress.key37");
$(document).unbind("keypress.key39");
```

That's called [namespaced events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events), i.e. labelling specific bindings using `<event_name>.<namespace>` (in your case, "keypress.key37 & keypress.key39").

Answer (score 0):

If the arrow keys are triggered when you are focused anywhere on the page, then the event handlers are probably bound to the window or document, unbind like so:

```
$(window).unbind('keydown');
$(document).unbind('keydown');
```

If you want to unbind the event ONLY for 'left' or 'right' arrow key, you can stop the event like so:

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37: // left arrow
            e.preventDefault;
            e.stopPropagation;
            break;
        case 39: // right arrow
            e.preventDefault;
            e.stopPropagation;
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that unbind all keydown events? I want specifically just for left and right arrows!

Comment: `e.preventDefault;` should be a function call `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend debugging to find where these events are bound(or even if they're bound). If these are bound with jQuery, they will be viewable via .data();

eg, in a console:

```
$('.suspected.element').data().events
```

If key events are truly the cause via some plugin, I would look to modify the binding of the events, rather than adding workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

```
function stopRKey(evt) {
      var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
      var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement :null);
      if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;}
}
document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
```